# Why does order not matter when multiplying two Apple Accelerate quaternions?

Tags: swift, math, quaternions

[Order is supposed to matter](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2131519/680791) in quaternion rotations, so this is rather bizarre to me:

```
var a = simd_quatf(angle: 20, axis: simd_float3(0,1,0))
var b = simd_quatf(angle: -10, axis: simd_float3(1,0,0))
print(a * b)
print(b * a)
```

The print statements have the same result:

`simd_quatf(real: -0.23801287, imag: SIMD3<Float>(-0.8046061, -0.15431823, 0.52167505))`

These two different orders for these rotations would not logically have the same outcome, so how could the concatenated rotation be identical?

I also tried `simd_mul()` which has the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Look closer. Are you sure that last element of the result doesn't have a different sign? Here is what I get in MATLAB if I assume radians for angles:

```
>> double(a*b)'
ans =
        -0.238012863697797        -0.804606057410128        -0.154318217253011         0.521675049161024
>> double(b*a)'
ans =
        -0.238012863697797        -0.804606057410128        -0.154318217253011        -0.521675049161024
```

And here is what I get in MATLAB if I assume degrees for the angles:

```
>> double(a*b)'
ans =
         0.981060262190407       -0.0858316511774313         0.172987393925089        0.0151344359013386
>> double(b*a)'
ans =
         0.981060262190407       -0.0858316511774313         0.172987393925089       -0.0151344359013386
```

Note the last element has a different sign.

Answer (score 1):

**Quaternion Multiplication**

Order of quaternions being multiplied in simd_mul matters. Mathematically, quaternion multiplication is not commutative,

```
ab != ba
```

Let's say you've built a SwiftUI app that allows you to orient an object in some graphical scene, as in SceneKit. You have,

```
origQ // Your object's original orientation
newQ. // The quaternion to update your object's orientation
```

Your object is being reorientated from gestures or other input.

Let's say from those inputs we construct the following rotation quaternions,

```
∆Q1 = simd_quatf(angle: degrees2Radians(45), axis: simd_float3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
∆Q2 = simd_quatf(angle: degrees2Radians(30), axis: simd_float3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0))
```

If you use the multiplication order,

```
newQ = simd_mul(∆Q1, origQ)
newQ = simd_mul(∆Q2, newQ)
```

you will be reorienting your object around the inertial, or fixed, coordinate axes.

Graphically, you'll get,

[image: Quaternion Rotation About Inertial Fixed Axes]

But, if you swap the multiplication order,

```
newQ = simd_mul(origQ, ∆Q1)
newQ = simd_mul(newQ, ∆Q2)
```

you will be reorienting your object around the local, or rotated, coordinate axes and not, as before the inertial, or fixed, coordinate axes.

Graphically, you'll get,

[image: Quaternion Rotation About The Rotating Axes]

So, the order that you multiply quaternions matters.

**Transforming a Vector**

There are two ways to rotate a vector with a rotations quaternion and their results can, just as quaternion multiplications order, differ.

Let's say we're doing a coordinate transformation from the SceneKit (Y = up) to an inertial frame (Z = up).

The position vector of an object you want to rotate from the SceneKit frame to the Z = up frame is,

```
origR = simd_float3(x: 1.0, y: 20.0, z: 680.0)
```

Let's say you have two rotations that are implemented in your scene,

```
∆Q1 = simd_quatf(angle: degrees2Radians(-90), axis: simd_float3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
∆Q2 = simd_quatf(angle: degrees2Radians(-90), axis: simd_float3(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0))
```

Swift's implementation of SIMD has a buit-in function for transforming a vector with a quaternion,

```
func simd_act(_ q: simd_quatf, _ v: simd_float3) -> simd_float3
```

If you execute the following operations,

```
newQ = simd_mul(origQ, ∆Q1)
newR = ∆Q1.act(origR)
 
newQ = simd_mul(newQ, ∆Q2)
newR = ∆Q2.act(newR)
```

Graphically you will get,

[image: Coordinate Transformation Local Axes]

The graphical representation looks good.

The results for the vector rotation will be,

```
origR = simd_float3(x: 1.0, y: 20.0, z: 680.0)
newR  = simd_float3(x: -680.0, y: 1.0, z: -20.0)
```

That doesn't look right!

So what is happening? `simd_act(_ q: simd_quatf, _ v: simd_float3) -> simd_float3` uses the following convention for vector transformation,

```
newR = Q * origR * Q-1
```

which is clearly not working in rotating the vector properly in our current scheme. The problem is not the oder of the above operations since quaternion multiplication is associative, e.g.,

```
(ab)c == a(bc)
```

But there is another way to rotate, or transform, the vector, rotation quaternion,

```
newR = Q-1 * origR * Q
```

And if this is formed into a function, let's call it,

```
func rotate(_ q: simd_quatf, _ v: simd_float3) -> float3
```

and used as follows,

```
newQ = simd_mul(origQ, ∆Q1)
newR = rotate(∆Q1, origR)
 
newQ = simd_mul(newQ, ∆Q2)
newR = rotate(∆Q2, newR)
```

The resulting transformed vector is,

```
origR = simd_float3(x: 1.0, y: 20.0, z: 680.0)
newR  = simd_float3(x: 680.0, y: 1.0, z: 20.0)
```

And that is the correct transformation from the SceneKit space, where Y = up, to the inertial, or real world, space, where Z = up.

**Conclusions**

The order of quaternion multiplication matters. And the order of multiplying a quaternion and its conjugate with a vector matters too.

I hope this helps.